# How to combinated values from colomuns into rows title in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I got a data frame captured with selenium with this code:

```
try:
    coverage_limits = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//h5[text()=" Coverage Limits "]/following-sibling::table//tr[1]')
    header_cells_coverage = coverage_limits.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=".//th")
except NoSuchElementException:
    coverage_limits_data = [" "]


data_coverage = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//h5[text()=" Coverage Limits "]/following-sibling::table//tr[position()>=1]')
data_coverage_table = []
for row in data_coverage:
    cells = row.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=".//td")
    row_data = [cell.text for cell in cells]
    data_coverage_table.append(row_data)
print(data_coverage_table)


data_coverage_td1 = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//h5[text()=" Coverage Limits "]/following-sibling::table//tr[position()>=1]')
data_coverage_table_td1  = []
for row in data_coverage:
    cells = row.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=".//td[1]")
    row_data = [cell.text for cell in cells]
    data_coverage_table_td1 .append(row_data)
print(data_coverage_table_td1)


column_names_coverage = [cell.text for cell in header_cells_coverage]
column_names_coverage = ['HomeOwners ' + name for name in column_names_coverage]
print(column_names_coverage)
```

my data frame contains the next list with values assigned on rows:

```
data_covarage_table = [[], ['Dwelling (Coverage A)', '$574,600', '$1,500'], ['Other Structures (Coverage B)', '$57,460', '---'], ['Personal Property', '$287,300', '---'], ['Loss of Use (Coverage D)', '$114,920', '---'], ['Personal Liability (Coverage E)', '$100,000', '---'], ['Medical Payments', '$1,000', '---']]
```

and the code which I use to export in excel is:

```
df_from_coverage = pd.DataFrame(data_coverage_table, columns=column_names_coverage)
combined_df.to_excel("HomeOwners_results_v2.xlsx", index=False)
```

and the result is in this table:
[image]

what I am trying is the values from Column A from row 3 to row 8 to be added as the title of the columns and get the values like:

**Dwelling (Coverage A)Limit of liability**  **Other Structures (Coverage B)Limit**

```
      $574.600                               57$.460
```

and so one for the rest of the values and then to got the same idea but for

**Dwelling (Coverage A)Limit of Deduc**  **Other Structures (Coverage B)Deduc**

```
$1.500                                        ---
```

I was trying different methods with Transpose the DataFrame to swap columns and row functions also I was trying to find some answers on chatgpt but with no success, I am thinking the first time to combine these 2 and then make iterations to add the values but I do not have any id.

And the expected output I want the data from data_coverage_table to be the head of the table in Excel, only the first elements from that list and the values should be assigned to the specific column title, how is it in this image(added the headers manually in the excel)
[image]

I was thinking of doing an iteration like this:

```
for(th=1;th<=n,th++)
 columns = th + td(1);
 values[1] = td(2) 
 values[2] = td(3)
```

But I am not sure how to add the specific values under the columns.

The final excel want to be like:
[image]

After that, I want specific text:

```
text_1 = "NewWord1"
text_2 = "NewWord2"
```

Edit after the below comments:
Right now the data is added with the specific column names provided in the
the gettering data is using selenium and every time the names will be the same but the values will be changed as example the next data_coverage will be:

```
data_coverage_table = [['Dwelling (Coverage A)', '$54,600', '$2,500'], ['Other Structures (Coverage B)', '$55,460', '---'], ['Personal Property', '$247,300', '$10,000'], ['Loss of Use (Coverage D)', '$198,920', '---'], ['Personal Liability (Coverage E)', '$10,000', '---'], ['Medical Payments', '$6,000', '---']]
```

the expected result is the values to be added on the next row how I add manually in the image below:

[image]

Tried to use Concat but returning: Concat DataFrame Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand you correctly but based on the given `list`, you can use :

```
texts = ["Limit", "Deduct"]

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(data_coverage_table[1:]).set_index(0)
        .set_axis(texts, axis=1).melt(ignore_index=False)
        .set_index("variable", append=True)
)

df.index = map("{0[0]}-{0[1]}".format, df.index)

df.T.to_excel("HomeOwners_results.xlsx", index=False)
```

Alternatively, you can reshape the data before calling the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor :

```
from itertools import chain, product

data = list(zip(*data_covarage_table[1:]))
cols = list(map("{0[1]}-{0[0]}".format, product(texts, data[0])))

df = pd.DataFrame([chain(*data[1:])], columns=cols)

df.to_excel("HomeOwners_results.xlsx", index=False)
```

Output (*HomeOwners_results.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: Yes, but row number 3 from Excel should continue on row 2, can I do this?
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_coverage_table[1:]).set_index(0).T
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_coverage_table[2:]).set_index(0).T
df =  pd.concat([df_1,df_2) 
df.to_excel("HomeOwners_results.xlsx", index=False)
?

Comment: Can you show **exactly** how should look like the final `"HomeOwners_results.xlsx"` ?

Comment: Edit now the main question and add a picture with the final `"HomeOwners_results.xlsx"`

Comment: Thanks for amending. I updated the answer, can you check it out ?

Comment: Thank you! That is how I wanted to be the excel!

Comment: One more question can I change the name of the second value like the first should remain or add a new word and add a new word to the last?
Like:
Dwelling (Coverage A)+ Text1 and Dwelling (Coverage A) + Text2

Comment: Yes you can but where do you define `Text1`, `Text2`, .. ? Can you include them in your post ?

Comment: I added as variable is predefined values

Comment: I suggest you to put the texts in a single list (*see update*) ;)

Comment: With the last edit with the chain and product I returned an error message:
raise ValueError(err) from err
ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns

Comment: But can I concat the same Excel file with the data frame to get other values on the next row? I asked because that list
`
data_coverage_table 
`
is get the data from this code:
`
data_coverage_td1 = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//h5[text()=" Coverage Limits "]/following-sibling::table//tr[position()>=1]')
data_coverage_table_td1  = []
for row in data_coverage:
    cells = row.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=".//td[1]")
    row_data = [cell.text for cell in cells]
    data_coverage_table_td1 .append(row_data)
`
So the data will be different at one moment

Comment: I think you need to update your post and provide a meaningful example of your input and the matching expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255915/discussion-between-timeless-and-geogrian-costea).